# Apps script JSON.parse() returns unexpected result, how can I solve this?

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I am currently working on external app using Google Sheets and JSON for data transmission via Fetch API. I decided to mock the scenario (*for debugging matters*) then simple JSON comes from my external app through prepared Code.gs to be posted on Google sheets. The code snippet I run through Apps-scripts looks like this:

```
function _doPost(/* e */) {
  // const body = e.postData.contents;
  const bodyJSON = JSON.parse("{\"coords\" : \"123,456,789,112,113,114,115,116\"}" /* instead of : body */);
  const db = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  db.getRange("A1:A10").setValue(bodyJSON.coords).setNumberFormat("@"); // get range, set value, set text format
}
```

The problem is the result I get: `123,456,789,112,113,000,000,000` As you see, `starting from 114 and the later` it outputs me `000,...` instead. I thought, okay I am gonna explicitly specify format to be returned (saved) as a text format. If the output within the range selected on Google Sheets UI : Format -> Number -> it shows me Text.

However, interesting magic happens, let's say if I would update the **body** of the JSON to be parsed something like that when the sequence of numbers composed of 2 digits instead of 3 (**notice**: *those are actual part of string, not true numbers, separated by comma!*) : `"{\"coords\" : \"123,456,789,112,113,114,115,116,17,18\"}"` it would not only show response result as expected but also brings back *id est* fixes the "corrupted" values hidden under the `000,...` as so : "{"coords" : "123,456,789,112,113,**114,115,116**,17,18 "}".

Even Logger.log() returns me initial JSON input as expected. I really have no clue what is going on. I would really appreciate one's correspondence to help solving this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try directly assigning a JSON formatted string in your bodyJSON variable instead of parsing a set of string using JSON.parse.

Part of your code should look like this:

```
  const bodyJSON = {
    "coords" : "123,456,789,112,113,114,115,116"
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your co-operation. Unfortunately, even without JSON.parse() it returns same culprit of 000,... . Interesting fact, that if for example range changed to single cell e.g. db.getRange("A11").setValue(bodyJSON.coords).setNumberFormat("@"); it returns result as expected i.e. 123,456,789,112,113,114,115,116

Comment: Also, if comma could be removed as so {"coords" : "123456789112113114115116"} just before pushing data in Google Sheets it works without a problem. Unfortunately my app returns pair of coordinates, what's why I cannot follow this workaround approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

**I found simple workaround after all**: just added the preceding pair of zeros **0,0**,123,... at the very beginning of coords. This prevents so called culprit I defined in my issue. If anyone interested, the external app I am building currently, it's called Hotspot widget : play around with DOM, append a marker which coordinates (coords) being pushed through Apps-script and saved to Google Sheets. I am providing a link with instructions on how to set up one's own copy of the app. It's a decent start-off for learning Vanilla JavaScript basics including simple database approach on the fly. Thank you and good luck!

[Hotspot widget on Github](https://github.com/projektorius96/hotspot.js)